# Launching Google Maps in Android, only gridlines are visible

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

It's been 3 months now and I am still having an issue when launching Google Maps using Android.

I am still ending up with GridLines. I have seen several forum suggestions where they talk about using a wrong API key.

I used the command below to generate the API key and yet the problem hasn't been resolved.

> keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass andro id -keypass
>   android -keystore debug.keystore

All I want is to display the default map using:

```
public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
{    

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the manifest, I have included the following:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

and:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also, when I close the emulator, I am getting a message:

> "emulator window was out of view and was recentred"

Comment: Have you followed the instruction for [obtaining the Map Key](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)?

Comment: Try to renew your API key. It works for me.